# Need to implement recaptcha

Tags: php, recaptcha

Can somebody help me out adding recaptcha on this code?

Here is my php register.

```
//if form has been submitted process it
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

//very basic validation
if($_POST['username'] == ''){
    $error[] = 'Username is required.';
}else if(strlen($_POST['username']) < 6){
    $error[] = 'Username is too short. (6 Chars)';
}else if(strlen($_POST['username']) > 32){
    $error[] = 'Username is too long. (32 Chars)';
}else if(preg_match('/[^a-z0-9_]/', $_POST['username'])){
    $error[] = 'Only a-z, 0-1 and _ are allowed in username.';
} else {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT username FROM members WHERE username = :username');
    $stmt->execute(array(':username' => $_POST['username']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($row['username'])){
        $error[] = 'Username provided is already in use.';
    }

}

//email validation
 if($_POST['email'] == ''){
    $error[] = 'Email Address is required.';
}else if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
    $error[] = 'Please enter a valid Email Address';
} else {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT email FROM members WHERE email = :email');
    $stmt->execute(array(':email' => $_POST['email']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($row['email'])){
        $error[] = 'Email Address provided is already in use.';
    }

}

 if($_POST['mobile'] == ''){
    $error[] = 'Mobile Number is required.';
}else if(!is_numeric($_POST['mobile'])){
    $error[] = 'Mobile Number should be numeric.';
}else if(strlen($_POST['mobile']) < 10){
    $error[] = 'Mobile Number is too short.';
}
else if(strlen($_POST['mobile']) > 10){
    $error[] = 'Mobile Number is too long.';
} else {
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT mobile FROM members WHERE mobile = :mobile');
    $stmt->execute(array(':mobile' => $_POST['mobile']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    if(!empty($row['mobile'])){
        $error[] = 'Mobile Number is already in use.';
    }
}   

if($_POST['password'] == ''){
    $error[] = 'Password is required.';
}else if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 6){
    $error[] = 'Password is too short. (6 Chars)';
}else if(strlen($_POST['passwordConfirm']) < 6){
    $error[] = 'Confirm password was too short. (6 Chars)';
}else if($_POST['password'] != $_POST['passwordConfirm']){
    $error[] = 'Passwords do not match.';
}

//if no errors have been created carry on
if(!isset($error)){

    //hash the password
    $hashedpassword = $user->password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_BCRYPT);

    //create the activasion code
    $activation = md5(uniqid(rand(),true));


    $usrname = str_replace(' ', '', $_POST['username']);
    $usrname = preg_replace('/\s+/','',$_POST['username']);
    try {

        //insert into database with a prepared statement
        $stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO members (username,password,email,mobile,active) VALUES (:username, :password, :email, :mobile, :active)');
        $stmt->execute(array(
            ':username' => strtolower($usrname),
            ':password' => $hashedpassword,
            ':email' => $_POST['email'],
            ':mobile' => $_POST['mobile'],
            ':active' => $activation
        ));

        header('Location: register.php?action=joined');
        exit;

    //else catch the exception and show the error.
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        $error[] = $e->getMessage();
    }

}

}
```

Comment: There are variety of tutorial available online on recaptcha integration. Have you googled it? There is a [tutsplus link](http://smal.me.pn/QLCJ)

Comment: i tried but im not able to im plant it. im still new to php, my website developed by others. i be grateful of someone would help ,me add this to block spammers

Comment: The tutorial linked by @Thamilan is the first Google result but it's actually quite useless and old; at least a couple of comments are useful. Here on  [GitHub](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/tree/d3274db7c061770472b8eff8a7dbae0871f6cf03) you can find a better explanation. I would like to answer you with a fully working code but I'm working on it as well

Answer (score 0):

Here the explanation to integrate ReCaptcha 2.0. I just tested it on my website and it works.

1. Request [here](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin) the keys (public and private) you'll need to integrate in your HTML and PHP code
2. Go to [GitHub reCAPTCHA PHP](https://github.com/google/recaptcha/tree/d3274db7c061770472b8eff8a7dbae0871f6cf03) and download the ZIP file (or follow the instructions to install it; I downloaded it and uploaded it on my server)

## HTML

Insert this in your `<head>` tag to call the Google reCAPTCHA API

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

And this is how your form will appear

```
<form action="..." method="POST">
  _list of your inputs_

  <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key(the_public_one)"></div>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

## PHP

Include the file `autoload.php` that you find in the ZIP you've downloaded

```
<?php require('path_where_you_uploaded_the_folder/recaptcha/src/autoload.php'); ?>
```

And the simplest code to perform the check is:

```
<?php
$siteKey = 'your_public_key'; //ex. 6OfGWERRRRt17YkojJGk2mEeM8fgEPKSpiPe
$secret = 'your_private_key';
$recaptcha = new \ReCaptcha\ReCaptcha($secret);
$resp = $recaptcha->verify($_POST['g-recaptcha-response'], $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); //the values for: $gRecaptchaResponse, $remoteIp
if ($resp->isSuccess()) {
    echo 'GREAT!'; //insert here the code you'll want to process if the verification is ok or the value you want to return (if this code is inserted in a function)
} else {
    $errors = $resp->getErrorCodes();
    echo 'NOOPE..'; //print_r($errors): you'll see which is/are the error
}

?>
```

The form passes to the PHP script the property `g-recaptcha-response`; if you `print_r($_POST['g-recaptcha-response']` or you `print_r($_POST)` you'll see that if the check is positive (you haven't been marked as a robot), the value of `g-recaptcha-response` is a long alphanumeric string.